# ImportError: cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv'

Tags: python, installation, python-dotenv

I am trying to import load_dotenv from dotenv using:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dotenv/__init__.py)
```

I have tried uninstalling and then re-installing dotenv using:

```
pip3 install python-dotenv
```

But I am still unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is your file called "dotenv.py"? If so, change it

Comment: Nope. None of my files are named "dotenv.py" @DeepSpace

Comment: Add the full stacktrace and the output of `where pip3`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: error shows you full path to file - you could open it and see what you have in this file. Maybe you installed wrong module. Or maybe you have very old version and it doesn't have this function. You may also check `import dotenv` and `print( dotenv.__file__ )` to see if it imports correct module.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you installed the wrong `dotenv` package. Try:

```bash
pip uninstall dotenv
pip install python-dotenv
```